# application.css isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my application.css:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 * 
 *= require bootstrap 
 *= require bootstrap-responsive 
 *= require style
```

For some reason none of my css styles are being applied. When I view source and open application.css, the file is exactly the same. It's not compiling it. The application.js is compiling just fine!

my gemfile: https://gist.github.com/1748054

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Fixed it by adding `*/`

Comment: Can we have a look at your Gemfile?

Comment: Any idea what might be causing this though? I've never had this problem in the past.

Comment: how are you running the server, if you use `rails s` are there any hints in the command line output when you browse to a url?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have:

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
```

set in your `config/application.rb`

Also this is a bit of a shot in the dark but don't you need to have a line like this:

```
*=require_self
```

before anything else. I always use sass imports to include my stylesheets with more precision. So mine would look like this:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 */
@import "bootstrap.css";
@import "bootstrap-responsive.css";
@import "style.css";
```

Then just make sure your file is named `application.css.scss`

Comment: renaming your application.scss will throw up SASS errors due to bad syntax. I've fixed the error though! it seems that I forgot the `*/` at the end

Comment: :3 frustrating! I spent 90 minutes figuring this out. Sigh.